# send a picture via jQuery to PHP - FormData is everytime empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, multipartform-data

I read some SO questions but nothing could help me.

I've a normal HTML form:

```
<form id="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" name="my_image_upload" id="my_image_upload" multiple="false" />
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" />
  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'my_image_upload', 'my_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
  <div class="button-reg-box">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-set-picture">Profilbild bearbeiten</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is my jQuery function:

```
jQuery('#featured_upload').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    SetAndChangePicture();
});

function SetAndChangePicture() {
    var test = new FormData(this); <-- empty :(
    console.log(test);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: dmd_output_favorites_obj.ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: "dmd_picture",
            formdata: new FormData() <-- empty too but I want to test above
        },
        success: function (data) {
            //jQuery('#MemberAreaChangeInterests .alert-success').show();
        }
    });
}
```

This `var test = new FormData(this);` is everytime empty.

I tried `this` and the jQuery selector of the form. Both aren't working.

EDIT:

Error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

EDIT:

Here is a picture of my debug:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try Following code :

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('image', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
```

**Sending form**

Ajax request with jQuery will looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Your url here',
    data: formData,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    //...Other options like success and etc
})
```

Comment: I debug the var formData but this var is still empty.

Comment: @cgee should try remove SetAndChangePicture paste code there

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var formData = $('#featured_upload').serialize();
```

This will give you the form details

Comment: It is still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

add a input type hidden with the action

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" id="post_id" value="dmd_picture" />
```

change data to:

```
 data: new FormData(jQuery('#featured_upload')[0]);
```

use the following ajax properties

```
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
```

Note: don't use async:false;

Comment: Still empty and this new error appears. Uncaught TypeError: k.toLowerCase is not a function

Comment: FormData does not accepts argument right ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData

Comment: what is empty? how do you know is empty?

Comment: I debugging with firebug... it is empty. $_FILE in PHP is also empty.

Comment: can you provide the php function for this ajax reuqest?